# Improve design with IOC/DI

Tags: c#, oop, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm currently trying to find a better design for my multi-module solution using DI/IOC, but now I'm somehow lost. I have a solution where different kind of entities can be distributed to recipients via different channels.
This is a simplified version of my classes:

```
#region FTP Module
public interface IFtpService
{
    void Upload(FtpAccount account, byte[] data);
}

public class FtpService : IFtpService
{
    public void Upload(FtpAccount account, byte[] data)
    {
    }
}
#endregion

#region Email Module
public interface IEmailService :IDistributionService
{
    void Send(IEnumerable<string> recipients, byte[] data);
}

public class EmailService : IEmailService
{
    public void Send(IEnumerable<string> recipients, byte[] data)
    {
    }
}
#endregion

public interface IDistributionService { }
#region GenericDistributionModule

public interface IDistributionChannel
{
    void Distribute();
}

public interface IDistribution
{
    byte[] Data { get; }

    IDistributionChannel DistributionChannel { get; }

    void Distribute();
}

#endregion

#region EmailDistributionModule
public class EmailDistributionChannel : IDistributionChannel
{
    public void Distribute()
    {
        // Set some properties
        // Call EmailService???
    }

    public List<string> Recipients { get; set; } 
}

#endregion

#region FtpDistributionModule
public class FtpDistributionChannel : IDistributionChannel
{
    public void Distribute()
    {
        // Set some properties
        // Call FtpService???
    }

    public FtpAccount ftpAccount { get; set; }
}

#endregion

#region Program
public class Report
{
    public List<ReportDistribution> DistributionList { get; private set; }

    public byte[] reportData{get; set; }
}

public class ReportDistribution : IDistribution
{
    public Report Report { get; set; }

    public byte[] Data { get { return Report.reportData; } }

    public IDistributionChannel DistributionChannel { get; private set; }

    public void Distribute()
    {
        DistributionChannel.Distribute();
    }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EmailService emailService = new EmailService();
        FtpService ftpService = new FtpService();
        FtpAccount aAccount;
        Report report;

        ReportDistribution[] distributions =
        {
            new ReportDistribution(new EmailDistributionChannel(new List<string>("test@abc.xyz", "foo@bar.xyz"))),
            new ReportDistribution(new FtpDistributionChannel(aAccount))
        };
        report.DistributionList.AddRange(distributions);

        foreach (var distribution in distributions)
        {
            // Old code:
            // if (distribution.DistributionChannel is EmailDistributionChannel)
            // {
            //     emailService.Send(...);        
            // }else if (distribution.DistributionChannel is FtpDistributionChannel)
            // {
            //     ftpService.Upload(...);
            // }else{ throw new NotImplementedException();}

            // New code:
            distribution.Distribute();
        }
    }
}
#endregion
```

In my current solution it is possible to create and store persistent `IDistribution` POCOs (I'am using a `ReportDistribution` here) and attach them to the distributable entity (a `Report` in this example).
E.g. someone wants to distribute an existing `Report` via Email to a set of recipients. Therefore he creates a new `ReportDistribution' with an`EmailDistributionChannel'. Later he decides to distribute the same `Report` via FTP to a specified FtpServer. Therefore he creates another `ReportDistribution` with an `FtpDistributionChannel`.
It is possible to distribute the same `Report` multiple times on the same or different channels.

An Azure Webjob picks up stored `IDistribution` instances and distributes them. The current, ugly implementation uses if-else to distribute `Distributions` with a `FtpDistributionChannel` via a (low-level) `FtpService` and `EmailDistributionChannels` with an `EmailService`.

I'm now trying to implement the interface method `Distribute()` on `FtpDistributionChannel` and `EmailDistributionChannel`. But for this to work the entities need a reference to the services. Injecting the Services into the entities via ConstructorInjection seems to be considered bad style.

[Mike Hadlow](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.de/2010/12/second-commandment-thy-entity-shalt-not.html) comes up with three other solutions:

1. Creating Domain Services. I could e.g. create a `FtpDistributionService`, inject a `FtpService` and write a `Distribute(FtpDistributionChannel distribution)` method (and also a `EmailDistributionService`). Apart from the drawback mentioned by Mike, how can I select a matching `DistributionService` based on the `IDistribution` instance? Replacing my old if-else with another one does not feel right
2. Inject `IFtpService/EMailService` into the `Distribute()` method. But how should I define the `Distribute()` method in the `IDistribution` interface? `EmailDistributionChannel` needs an `IEmailService` while `FtpDistributionChannel` need an `IFtpService`.
3. Domain events pattern. I'm not sure how this can solve my problem.

Let me try to explain why I came up with this quite complicated solution:
It started with a simple list of Reports. Soon someone asked me to send reports to some recipients (and store the list of recipients). Easy!

Later, someone else added the requirement to send a report to a FtpAccount. Different FtpAccounts are managed in the application, therefore the selected account should also be stored.
This was to the point where I added the IDistributionChannel abstraction. Everything was still fine.

Then someone needed the possibility to also send some kind of persistent Logfiles via Email. This lead to my solution with IDistribution/IDistributionChannel.
If now someone needs to distribute some other kind of data, I can just implement another IDistribution for this data. If another DistributionChannel (e.g. Fax) is required, I implement it and it is available for all distributable entities.

I would really appreciate any help/ideas.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do yo create interfaces for the `FtpAccount`? The class is isolated and provide no behavior that need to be abstracted away.

Let's start with your original problem and build from there. The problem as I interpret it as that you want to send something to a client using a different set of mediums.

By expressing it in code it can be done like this instead:

```
public void SendFileToUser(string userName, byte[] file)
{
    var distributions = new []{new EmailDistribution(), new FtpDistribution() };        
    foreach (var distribution in distributions)
    {
        distribution.Distribute(userName, file);
    }
}
```

See what I did? I added a bit of context. Because your original use case was way to generic. It's not often that you want to distribute some arbitrary data to an arbitrary distribution service.

The change that I made introduces a domain and a real problem.

With that change we can also model the rest of the classes a bit different.

```
public class FtpDistributor : IDistributor
{
    private FtpAccountRepository _repository = new FtpAccountRepository();
    private FtpClient _client = new FtpClient();

    public void Distribute(string userName, byte[] file)
    {
        var ftpAccount = _repository.GetAccount(userName);
        _client.Connect(ftpAccount.Host);
        _client.Authenticate(ftpAccount.userName, ftpAccount.Password);
        _Client.Send(file);
    }
}
```

See what I did? I moved the responsibility of keeping track of the FTP account to the actual service. In reality you probably have an administration web or similar where the account can be mapped to a specific user.

By doing so I also isolated all handling regarding FTP to within the service and therefore reduced the complexity in the calling code.

The email distributor would work in the same way.

When you start to code problems like this, try to go from top->down. It's otherwise easy to create an architecture that seems to be SOLID while it doesn't really solve the actual business problem.

**Update**

I've read your update and I don't see why you must use the same classes for the new requirements?

> Then someone needed the possibility to also send some kind of persistent Logfiles via Email

That's an entirely different use case and should be separated from the original use case. Create new code for it. The `SmtpClient` in .NET is quite easy to us and do not need to be abstracted away.

> If now someone needs to distribute some other kind of data, I can just implement another IDistribution for this data.

Why? what complexity are you trying to hide?

> If another DistributionChannel (e.g. Fax) is required, I implement it and it is available for all distributable entities

No. Distributing thing A is not the same as distributing thing B. You can't for instance transport parts of a large bridge on an airpane, either a freight ship or a truck is required.

What I'm trying to say is that creating too generic abstractions/contracts to promote code reuse seems like a good idea, but it usually just make your application more complex or less readable.

Create abstractions when there is real complexity issues and not on before hand.

Comment: Thank you jgauffin!
I think my initial sample code was over-simplified. I changed it to be closer to my real implementation and added some additional comments.
Your code looks interesting, but I'm not sure whether it suits my requirements. Maybe you can have another look at my edited question.

Comment: I'm feeling stupid now, but I think I still do not really understand your proposed solution.
My Distribution/EmailDistribution/FtpDistribution-Stuff is developed in individual projects/nuget packages. Therefore it is quite easy to add Distribution functionality to another app.

I'm not trying to hide complexity, but I want to create reusable modules.
What do you suggest? Create an abstract `AbstractReportDistribution` class with inherited `ReportEmailDistribution`, `ReportFtpDistribution`, `ReportFaxDistribution` classes and also `AbstractLogDistribution` and decendants?

Comment: ... And If I need to add another distributable, I have to copy&paste code for all distribution options ? If I need another distribution option (e.g. Dropbox) I'll have to implement `XYZDropboxDistribution`classes for all distributables?
P.S. The `IDistributable` has some additional properties like Date, Distributor, DistributionStatus...

I really appreciate your help, but today I don't get your point...